# How does a kernel patch propagate into distribution updates?

Tags: git, kernel

I have been affected by, and helped to debug, a kernel bug. A patch has been created by the maintainer of the module, and submitted.

I am interested to know how the patch propagates through to binary update releases. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, which uses kernel 3.13, so, for me, the patch will need to be backported at the very least.

Ideally I would like to pin my kernel on an existing, pre-bug version (3.12 as it happens), and then, when the patch becomes available as an update, un-pin it. **How will I know when to un-pin?** Can I somehow track the progress of the patch through the system?

(I hope that this question is generic enough to be useful to others, but as a matter of interest, [this is the bug in question](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=72891) and [this is the patch commit email](https://www.marc.info/?l=linux-usb&m=141770652118414&w=2).)

Comment: If I remember right, when the patch works its way through release the bug is updated. Why not just apply the patch yourself?

Comment: The patch being released on kernel.org is distinct from the patch making its way into various binary distributions, though. As for applying the patch myself - certainly I can do that, but ultimately I want to use the automatically updating distribution binaries, so that I get security fixes and so on, and so the question is the same - how do I know when the fix has made it into my particular distribution, so I know when I can start using their binaries again?